# Confusing author guidelines

Tags: copyright, legal

I am going to publish an article [on this website](http://www.90min.in/).

I was going through author guidelines section and I found this piece of information:

> By sharing any contribution you agree to grant 90min.in permission to
>   use the material in any way 90min.in deems it fit (including modifying
>   and adapting it for operational and editorial reasons) in any media
>   worldwide.

Does this mean I loose all the right over my article.  If they use the material elsewhere will they mention my name in credits ?

Please explain ?

Comment: There is nothing to explain. Yup, if you do that, you will loose all your rights.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer so I will preface this with saying the following is my opinion of what it means: The law reads literally, and I think NO you don't lose all rights, but you are ***granting*** them unlimited use.

***"Permission to use the material in any way [we] deems it fit"*** means ANY way you can think of, including publishing it for money under their own name, editing and modifying it and selling it. They did not mention selling it but they do not have to mention that specifically, the right to sell it is included as part of your granting them permission to use it in ANY WAY they see fit.

They may also "deem" it fit to publish for money without giving you credit for it. That is a right you can legally surrender, many ghost writers and song writers do surrender it.